# Global HTTP Header Manager with http script of uploading file

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Im writing script which have https request for uploading file. For this script I need to overwrite 'Content-Type' from global http header manager.
Is there any way to perform this in jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

1. As per [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) documentation:

   > JMeter now supports multiple Header Managers. The header entries are merged to form the list for the sampler. **If an entry to be merged matches an existing header name, it replaces the previous entry.** This allows one to set up a default set of headers, and apply adjustments to particular samplers.
2. HTTP Header Manager respects [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so if you need to override a header - add another HTTP Header Manager **as a child of the Sampler** which header you need to "override"

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but in this case I cant set 'Content-Type' header in inner 'HTTP Header Manager' because it needs be in next style: 
multipart/form-data; boundary=someBoundary.
But when Im trying to use any value for boundary(even taken from successfull request) it give me response, saying about wrong format.

JMeter automatically set the right value in 'Content-Type' in case enabled 'Use multipart/formdata' checkbox in http request settings.

But If I have the global 'HTTP Header Manager', it overrides value generated by  'Use multipart/formdata' checkbox